# Find files modified within 24 hours linux server

Tags: linux, centos

I need to find files modified last 24 hours without subfolders. I am having this command

```
find /var/www/html/test/ -mtime -1 -type f -exec ls -l {} \;
```

This will show all the modified file within folder and subfolder. But I need only the particular folder that modified in last 24 hours.

So please anyone help and tell me the command to show modified with in the parent folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add `-maxdepth 1`

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mtime -1 -type f -exec ls -l {} \;
```

Comment: Thanks for you quick reply. 
Is there any chance to exclude 1 or 2 particular folders.

Comment: You can use `grep -v` to exclude any folder from the result.

Comment: Sorry could you please tell me the exact command to exclude one folder.
find /var/www/html/test/ -maxdepth 1 -mtime -1 -type f -exec ls -l {} \;

Where I need to add grep -v incase i need to exclude testsub folder what is the command.

Comment: `find . -maxdepth 1 -mtime -1 -type f -exec ls -l {} \; | grep -v testsub`